# Bash in chroot strange key movements

Tags: linux, bash, chroot

I'm trying to set up a chroot environment with only bash in it. This is what I have so far:

```
[root@free]# tree .
.
├── bin -> usr/bin/
├── dev
├── etc
│   ├── bash.bash_logout
│   ├── bash.bashrc
│   ├── inputrc
│   └── profile
├── lib -> usr/lib/
├── lib64 -> usr/lib64/
├── proc
├── sys
└── usr
    ├── bin
    │   └── bash
    ├── lib
    │   ├── libc.so
    │   ├── libc.so.6
    │   ├── libdl.so
    │   ├── libdl.so.2
    │   ├── libncursesw.so.6
    │   ├── libreadline.so
    │   ├── libreadline.so.7
    │   ├── libreadline.so.7.0
    │   ├── libtinfo.so
    │   └── libtinfo.so.6
    └── lib64
        └── ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

11 directories, 16 files
```

`ldd` lists the following for `bash`:

```
[root@free]# ldd /bin/bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd388a3000)
    libreadline.so.7 => /usr/lib/libreadline.so.7 (0x00007fa6e0baa000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa6e09a6000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa6e05ea000)
    libncursesw.so.6 => /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6 (0x00007fa6e037d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa6e10d8000)
```

Entering the chroot environment already works (`I have no name!` is fine since i have not jet copied the passwd file):

```
[root@free jail]# chroot .
[I have no name!@jail]#
```

**The problem**
is that if I type in `p` `e` `backspace` `w` `d` the line will look like:

```
[I have no name!@jail]#pe wd
```

executing it with enter will execute `pwd` and print

```
/
```

also the arrow keys (left and right) acting weird like printing multiple characters but not moving the cursor `p` `d` `left` `w` leads to `pdwd` . This does not happen in `bash` outside of the chroot.

**How can I fix this?**

Did I forget to copy a library or something? Is it a `libreadline` problem (I already copied `etc/inputrc`)? Or could it be a `libncursesw` problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a look at [a script to generate minimal chroots](https://gist.github.com/schnell18/7287068) and noticed that you're missing the `/usr/share/terminfo/` directory, which is used by libcurses and deals with terminal command sequences. In addition to some other files that will likely be necessary (`/etc/resolv.conf`, etc.), that's what I'd look at trying.

Answer (score 3):

Reading `/etc/terminfo/README`, as seen on [http://web.archive.org/web/20120621035133/http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard/keyboard.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20120621035133/http://www.ibb.net/%7Eanne/keyboard/keyboard.html), helped me finding out where terminfo was located:

> cat /etc/terminfo/README
>
> This directory is for system-local terminfo descriptions. By default,
> ncurses will search ${HOME}/.terminfo first, then /etc/terminfo (this
> directory), then /lib/terminfo, and last not least /usr/share/terminfo.

As `/usr/share/terminfo/` was empty (but a common answer on many websites), on a recent distro it seems that `/lib/terminfo/` is the good location.

So copy to your chrooted directory the directory which is not empty, be it:

- /etc/terminfo/
- /lib/terminfo/
- /usr/share/terminfo/